# List all title + ID of a googledrive content folder in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Given the timing of Google Colab, I usually store my Google Drive activities in a DDMMYY folder (Day, month and year). Every day the content is stored like this. Images, code, drafts, etc.

I mount Google Drive using the default form of Google Colab and not PyDrive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive',force_remount=True)
```

Is there any way to generate title + ID of all folder contents of the day (DDMMYY) in a list (csv, xml or json)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This metadata is stored in extended file attributes. You can retrieve them using the `xattr` command.

Here's a complete example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16ylOxW_AyON1CMvjlT8rBAlDTpnR5fEa

The key bits:

```
# Installing the xattr tool.
!apt-get install -qq xattr

# Retrieving the file ID for a file in `"/content/drive/My Drive/"`:
!xattr -p 'user.drive.id' file

# Retrieving the title
!xattr -p "user.drive.itemprotostr" created.txt | grep 'title:'
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but it's not what I expected yet. I was expecting a list of all the contents of the folder at once and not looking for one by one.

Comment: Combine `xattr` with `find -exec`, which will run a command on all files matching a find predicate. [See here for more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec).